# JQuery and ASP Calendar Browser Issues

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, jquery-plugins

The problem I'm getting is that when trying to select the calendar icon, the calendar doesn't appear.

This occurs within Firefox and IE10, the offending section is within a ListView, selectedItemTemplate in ASP.net.

The plugin I'm using for this: http://code.google.com/p/dyndatetime/

The scripts are all in the masterpage maincontent which is where the ListView is contained. The calendar is used twice in the same page and relates to two separate sections (create new, which has a collapsible panel and edit item) within the page.

Below are the relevant code snippets, this works properly in Internet Explorer 11 and Chrome so I'm not sure what is causing this issue in Firefox and Internet Explorer 10.

Many thanks in advance!

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
         $("#StartDateTextBox").dynDateTime({
             showsTime: true,
             ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
             daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
             align: "BR",
             electric: false,
             singleClick: false,
             displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
             button: ".next()"
         });
         $("#ExpiryDateTextBox").dynDateTime({
             showsTime: true,
             ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
             daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
             align: "BR",
             electric: false,
             singleClick: false,
             displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
             button: ".next()"
         });
         $("#StartDateCal").click(function () {
             $("#StartDateTextBox2").val('');
         });
         $("#StartDateTextBox2").dynDateTime({
             showsTime: true,
             ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
             daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
             align: "BR",
             electric: false,
             singleClick: false,
             displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
             button: ".next()"
         });
         $("#ExpiryDateCal").click(function () {
             $("#ExpiryDateTextBox2").val('');
         });
         $("#ExpiryDateTextBox2").dynDateTime({
             showsTime: true,
             ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
             daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
             align: "BR",
             electric: false,
             singleClick: false,
             displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
             button: ".next()"
         });
     });
```

Create new, panel extender sudo to show location and edit item:

```
<panel>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="StartDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>' Width="120px"/>
                    <img src="Images/calender.png" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ExpiryDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExpiryDate") %>' Width="120px"/>
                    <img src="Images/calender.png" />
```

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                <td  style="width:150px;">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="StartDateTextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>' Width="120px" />
                    <img id="StartDateCal"  src="Images/calender.png"/> 
                </td>
                <td  style="width:150px;">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ExpiryDateTextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExpiryDate") %>' Width="120px" />
                    <img id="ExpiryDateCal" src="Images/calender.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Look at the HTML that is rendered, specifically the relevant IDs, that will give you an idea as to what is going on.

Comment: Alos make sure to check for script errors in the console. There is a good chance something will be reported there.

Comment: HI @JonP I looked on FireFox and there were no errors, also the IE11 console to IE10 developer mode doesn't pick this up - strangely. Why would Chrome and IE11 be handling this fine and FF and 10 fail to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue, which I found whilst hunting down another problem I was having.

This all seems to stem from the AJAX HTML Tool Kit Extender, I don't know why, but it was interfering with all of my jQuery that wasn't in Chrome or IE 11.

Whilst this solves my issue with the calender displaying on Firefox it provides another issue where by I'll have to find and implement another HTML Text Editor.